# Unable to specify Device Profile using MQTT Gateway API

Tags: mqtt, gateway, thingsboard

We have started using ThingsBoard PE for our POC product to test if it will suit our needs.
We have an existing system which would act as a gateway between various types of IoT devices and ThingsBoard.

It seems that the communication could be implemented using MQTT Gateway API and I have successfuly used it to send connect/disconnect messages as well as telemetry upload. As stated in the gateway documentation, a new device is created if it does not yet exist in ThingsBoard. However, I am not sure how to specify device profile for each device based on device type. It seems that automatically created devices always have profile named "default" even if I have made a new profile and set it as default.
Is there any way to specify device profile in MQTT Gateway API?

Answer (score 0):

Add a key "type" in your connect message.

```
Topic: v1/gateway/connect
Message: {"device":"Device A", "type":"Type A"}
```